Код работает не так , как планировалось. Я должен угадать магическое число , но он вечно пишет одно и то же , чтобы я не писал
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(){
    int guess;
    int num;

    num=rand();

    do{
        std::cout<<"Enter your guess...\n";
        std::cin>>guess;
        if(guess==num){
            std::cout<<"molodec hahahha\n";
            std::cout<<num<<"this magic number HHAHA\n";
        }
        else{
            std::cout<<"nu shto plaki plaki????\n";
        }
            if(num>guess) std::cout<<"Tvoe chislo bol'she magicheskogo , NUZNO MEN'SHE\n";
            else std::cout<<"Tvoe chislo men'she magicheskogo , NUZNO BOL'SHE\n";
    }while(guess != num);  
}


Что значит «вечно пишет одно и то же» и что конкретно с этим не так?

@andreymal как я понял , когда я ввожу число и с первого раза не угадал, код выводит что у меня маленькое число. И если дальше написать хоть 1, то ничего не изменится , он будет также писать .

Не вижу у себя такого поведения, у меня выводимое сообщение на любом разе всегда меняется в полном соответствии с условиями guess==num и num>guess

if(num>guess) std::cout<<"Tvoe chislo bol'she magicheskogo , NUZNO MEN'SHE\n";

А если подумать? Твое число guess, оно в ветке, где истинно num > guess — и оно больше?!
Исправьте логику на верную, т.е. знак > на <...
И выход из цикла сразу при угадывании, а то после того как угадал, сначала напишет Tvoe chislo men'she magicheskogo , NUZNO BOL'SHE
https://ideone.com/MvlKrg

А обязательно этому числу давать конкретное значение? С рандомным значением не будет работать?

Вы имеете в виду на ideone? так не зная число, я же не мог подобрать ответы, которые демонстрируют, что все работает верно, вот и вынужден был взять конкретное число...
